# Exclude jni library file from androidTest build

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android library (AAR) and during build there are 2 native libraries are compiled, saying `libfoo.so` and `libfoo_test.so`.
I want to exclude `libfoo_test.so` from AAR itself and exclude `libfoo.so` from `<projectname>-debug-androidTest.apk` package. Android Gradle Plugin has a possibility to exclude files with `packagingOptions`, but it works for project itself and I didn't find how to use it for androidTest.
For AAR I solved the problem using Zip task which repacks AAR and excludes `libfoo_test.so`, but this approach doesn't look convenient for `<projectname>-debug-androidTest.apk` because I want to run this apk normally from Android Studio and I want to speedup compilation and reduce size.
Is there way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created custom keystore and ended up with the following:

```
tasks.configureEach { task ->
    if (task.name == 'packageDebugAndroidTest' || task.name == 'packageReleaseAndroidTest') {
        String buildVariant = task.name == 'packageDebugAndroidTest' ? 'debug' : 'release'
        String apkFilePath = "${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/androidTest/${buildVariant}/<project>-${buildVariant}-androidTest.apk"
        String apkSigner = "${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}/build-tools/${android.getBuildToolsVersion()}/apksigner"
        task.doLast {
            // Remove unnecessary libfoo.so from testing apk. This is the fastest approach. Another one is to use combination of
            // Zip task and Copy/Rename + Signing. Such approach is more portable and give better compression result, but it also
            // executes much longer
            def abis = ['x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a']
            abis.each { abi ->
                exec {
                    executable 'zip'
                    args '-d', apkFilePath, "lib/${abi}/libfoo.so"
                    // When zip utility is not available or when Android Studio is used or file already
                    // doesn't exists in archive just ignore possible error
                    ignoreExitValue true
                }
            }

            exec {
                executable apkSigner
                args 'sign', '-v',
                    '--ks', 'test-properties',
                    '--ks-pass', "pass:" + 'test-ks-pass',
                    '--key-pass', "pass:" + 'test-key-pass',
                    '--ks-key-alias', 'test-key-alias',
                    apkFilePath
            }
        }
    }
}
```